# font-size:0px and letter-spacing:10px displays differently in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

```
<html>
<head> 
    <style>
        ul{
            list-style-type:none;
            font-size:0px;
            letter-spacing:10px;
        }
        li{
            display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
    <ul>
        <li><img src="photo.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="photo.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="photo.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="photo.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="photo.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It's different in Firefox, Chrome and IE. In Firefox when I use `font-size:0px` and `letter-spacing:10px`, the `<li>` elements have the letter-spacing 10px but in Chrome and IE it doesn't work, why is that?

Comment: Perhaps a matter of browser defaults. Do you have different "minimal font size" settings on each? If that's not it, explain what "it doesn't work" means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only images inside the list, try changing your CSS to :

```
ul, ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `word-spacing` property, and not the `letter-spacing` ;)